# Place string on page

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am using `window.opener` to pass a string value from a child window to a parent window as so-

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
alert(clicked_id);

window.opener.document.write(clicked_id);
window.close ();
}
```

Where the `cliced_id` is the string I am passing back.

However I want to pass this back to a hidden input on the main page so I can use it again. The problem being is that I cannot specify where to put the string value on the main page and instead it just loads the string value in a new page without any of the original content.

Is it possible to pass back the string and keep the original HTML content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a an element on the original page with an id , you can reference that using `getElementById` and set the `innerHTML`:

eg, with an empty div on the page:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

You could use this code

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
    window.opener.document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = clicked_id;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer works a treat expect an accept in T minus 5 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `window.opener` is a complete `window` reference.

You could call `window.opener.myCallback(clicked_id)` or `window.opener.clickedId = clicked_id`

Answer (score 1):

hi why dont you store your  values in html5 storage objects such as sessionStorage/localStorage, visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. using this you can store intermediate values temporaryly/permanently locally and then access your values 
for storing values for a session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('label')
sessionStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

or store values permanently using

```
localStorage.getItem('label')
localStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

So you can store (temporarily) form data between multiple pages using html5 storage objects